# Why does Vim load unrelated ftplugins?

Tags: filetype, plugin-system, filetype-html, filetype-markdown

When I open a file with `.md` extension, the filetype is set to `markdown`, as expected. But the `ftplugin` for HTML is also loaded as I can see since I have some insert mode mappings in there to auto-insert html entities in place of umlauts. I opened `ftplugin/markdown.vim` and found this

```
" runtime! ftplugin/html.vim ftplugin/html_*.vim ftplugin/html/*.vim

setlocal comments=fb:*,fb:-,fb:+,n:> commentstring=>\ %s
setlocal formatoptions+=tcqln formatoptions-=r formatoptions-=o
setlocal formatlistpat=^\\s*\\d\\+\\.\\s\\+\\\|^[-*+]\\s\\+

if exists('b:undo_ftplugin')
  let b:undo_ftplugin .= "|setl cms< com< fo< flp<"
else
  let b:undo_ftplugin = "setl cms< com< fo< flp<"
endif
```

As you can see, I already commented out the first line. But vim still loads the html plugin. How can I influence this behaviour?

Comment: How and where do you define those insert mode mappings?

Comment: @romainl In `ftplugin/html.vim`, e.g. `inoremap <buffer> <Char-246> &ouml;` Which will automatically replace the ö as I type it.

Comment: Where is `ftplugin/markdown.vim`? Is it in `~/.vim/`?

Comment: Yes. Both html and md plugins are in `~/.vim/ftplugin/`

Comment: Did you also fix `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/markdown.vim`? I wouldn't call HTML "unrelated" to Markdown. Markdown is clearly intended to work with it.

Comment: @muru I fixed `/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/markdown.vim`, as I seemingly do not have a `vim74` directory there, but removing the offending line does nothing for me. And yes, they are not unrelated, but in my opinion it is a bit of a surprise that they should be so tightly coupled.

Comment: Ah, I see the correct file to edit is in `/usr/local/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/markdown.vim` since I compiled vim myself with `/usr/local` prefix. When changing that file, it works.

Comment: @oarfish Run `:scriptnames` after opening a markdown file. You can find out if other runtime directories are being used. (The list might be long, so you could filter out stuff by comparing against the output after just opening Vim.)

Comment: @oarfish excellent. I suppose that's your answer. I should have suggested `:e $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/markdown.vim`, instead of assuming things about your installation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vim already comes with Markdown support so what happens is that you have two Markdown ftplugins doing the same thing. Since you "fixed" one (`~/.vim/ftplugin/markdown.vim`) without "fixing" the other (`$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/markdown.vim`), your fix is simply overridden by the built-in ftplugin.

If you insist on disabling HTML support in markdown buffers you can simply "fix" the built-in ftplugin (and probably get rid of the extraneous one) but I'd suggest you reconsider your strategy. HTML is valid Markdown so yeah, HTML has its place in Markdown.

Comment: Yeah, but I need to use html entities in html, while they won't be correctly displayed in markdown. So my only option would be to drop the mappings which are very useful when edition html.

Comment: @oarfish You can use Vim's conceal feature to display your HTML entities as the glyphs they stand for: `:syntax match Entity "&ouml;" conceal cchar=ö`. See `:help syn-cchar` for details. Depending on your precise needs, this might be a better fix than removing all HTML support from Markdown buffers.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Markdown specification](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html), you are allowed to use *inline HTML* for any markup that is not covered by Markdown's syntax.  For this reason, the [Markdown configuration of Vim's `ftplugin`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/ftplugin/markdown.vim) also loads the HTML configuration, as you pointed out.

Instead of modifying this well-considered relation of default syntax configurations, I would suggest you modify your local `ftplugin/html.vim` so that commands very specific to HTML are only applied to files that are *purely* HTML.  You could do so, for example, by wrapping these settings in a block of

```
if (&filetype == 'html')
    " commands that only apply to files of filetype HTML
endif
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. I was going to create an `ftplugin` for Markdown files in my `after` sub-directory to over-ride some of the commands in my HTML `ftplugin` but this is more elegant.